# Serializing a JSON.NET JObject while filtering out certain properties

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a large arbitrary JSON structure as a `JObject` reference in my code.

I want to serialise this structure, except when I encounter a `JObject` containing a property called `type` with value `"encrypted"` then I want to remove the adjacent `data` property before writing the object.

In other words, if I encounter this:

```
{
  type: "encrypted",
  name: "some-name",
  data: "<base64-string>"
}
```

It will be serialized as this:

```
{
  type: "encrypted",
  name: "some-name"
}
```

I can't mutate the structure, and cloning it before mutating would be too inefficient, so I tried using a `JsonConverter` as follows:

```
public class RemoveEncryptedDataSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(JObject);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var o = (JObject)value;
        if (o.Value<string>("type") != "encrypted")
        {
            o.WriteTo(writer);
            return;
        }

        var copy = o.DeepClone();
        copy["data"]?.Parent.Remove();
        copy.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

However the `CanConvert` function only seems to be called with types not derived from `JToken`, so my `WriteJson` function is never called.

Is there another way to achieve this?

---

Edit: Here is some code you can use for testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ItShouldExcludeEncryptedData()
{
    var input = JObject.Parse(@"
    {
        a: {
            type: 'encrypted',
            name: 'some-name',
            data: 'some-data'
        }
    }");

    var expected = JObject.Parse(@"
    {
        a: {
            type: 'encrypted',
            name: 'some-name',
        }
    }");

    var output = input.ToString(Formatting.Indented, new RemoveEncryptedDataSerializer());

    Assert.AreEqual(
        expected.ToString(Formatting.Indented),
        output);
}
```

Comment: try to `return true;` instead of `return objectType == typeof(JObject);` in your `CanConvert` method and let me know it it works or not.

Comment: also try to add this method to your converter => `public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }`

Comment: Thanks @er-shoaib, unfortunately this does not work as `WriteJson` is still only called for the leave nodes of the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter needs to be built to handle a `JToken` and it must work recursively to ensure all the encrypted data is redacted.

I was able to get the following converter to work:

```
public class RemoveEncryptedDataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(JToken).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = (JToken)value;
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            bool omitDataProperty = token.Value<string>("type") == "encrypted";

            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                if (omitDataProperty && prop.Name == "data")
                    continue;

                writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, prop.Value);  // recurse
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in token.Children())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);  // recurse
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        else // JValue
        {
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0K61Bz

---

If you want to work with a `JsonWriter` directly through a stream, you can refactor the logic from the converter into a recursive extension method and use that.  You don't need a converter if you're not using the serializer.

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void RedactedWriteTo(this JToken token, JsonWriter writer)
    {
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            bool omitDataProperty = token.Value<string>("type") == "encrypted";

            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                if (omitDataProperty && prop.Name == "data")
                    continue;

                writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
                prop.Value.RedactedWriteTo(writer);  // recurse
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in token.Children())
            {
                item.RedactedWriteTo(writer);  // recurse
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        else // JValue
        {
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this, where `stream` is your output stream and `input` is your `JObject`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))  // or StringWriter if you prefer
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    input.RedactedWriteTo(writer);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l949HU

Comment: Thanks Brian, that's really helpful! Interestingly, my test still failed until I changed from using `ToString(...)` to using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)`. In reality I need to write to a stream, but `WriteTo(...)` also fails in the same way as `ToString(...)`. I'm a bit surprised they produce a different output, but this reproduces it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9lkFJO . Do you know how I could write to a stream while getting the same output as `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`?

Comment: @JamesThurley Updated my answer to show the approach for a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Newtonsoft JSON.Net library;

To conditionally serialize a property, add a method that returns boolean with the same name as the property and then prefix the method name with ShouldSerialize. The result of the method determines whether the property is serialized. If the method returns true then the property will be serialized, if it returns false then the property will be skipped.

For your example:

```
public class EncryptedData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeData()
    {
        // don't serialize the Data property if the Type equals "encrypted"
        return (Type != "encrypted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful tip, however in this case the JSON is an arbitrary structure and so I cannot deserialize it to a concrete type.